# Scope issue with stored procedure string parameter being returned from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure for creating inventory transactions that requires the assembly of a description. Since other inventory stored procedures will also need to assemble their descriptions similarly, I am trying to create a helper stored procedure.

This helper will use standard parameters and construct the description. The trouble I am having is returning the string `Description` back to the inventory transaction.

A Inventory transaction calls the helper this way:

```
declare @TransDescription nvarchar(256) 
declare @TransDescOut nvarchar(256)

EXEC [dbo].[sp_KF_Helpers_CreateInvTransDescription] 
     @TransactionTypeID, @UserName, @OwnerTypeID, @OwnerID, 
     @TransDesc = @TransDescOut OUTPUT

SET @TransDescription = @TransDescOut
```

Then I use `@TransDescription` as a value for inserting into column data.

The helper code is:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_KF_Helpers_CreateInvTransDescription]
    (   @TransactionTypeID int,
        @UserName nvarchar(256),
        @OwnerTypeID int,
        @OwnerID int,
        @TransDesc varchar(256) OUTPUT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @rslt int = 0
declare @strTyepID varchar(256) = @TransactionTypeID
declare @strOwnerID varchar(256) = @OwnerID
declare @intOwnerTypeID int = @OwnerTypeID
declare @OwnerStr varchar(256) = 'KF_'
declare @OwnerIDStr varchar(256) = (select Description from KF_OwnerType where ID = @intOwnerTypeID)

select @OwnerStr = @OwnerStr + @OwnerIDStr
declare @sql1 nvarchar(4000)

Select @sql1 = 'Select Top 1 (a.Description + '' - '' + ' + @OwnerStr + '.Name) TransDesc 
from KF_InventoryTransactionType a, KF_OwnerType c, ' + @OwnerStr + ' 
where a.ID = ' + @strTyepID + ' and ' 
+ @OwnerStr + '.ID = ' + @strOwnerID 

exec SP_EXECUTESQL @sql1, N'@TransDesc varchar output ', @TransDesc output
 End
```

As you can see, I am using dynamic SQL to generate the description. The problem is that the help code generates the correct description, but does not pass it back as output.

Anyone know why or where I am losing scope for returning my output description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to assign the variable.  Try:

```
select top 1 @TransDesc = a.Description + '' - '' + ' + @OwnerStr + '.Name
...
```

Also, change the part where you are declaring the parameter of the dynamic script (`@TransDesc`), or you will run into another issue. Currently the parameter is being declared like this:

```
@TransDesc varchar output
```

[which is equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) to

```
@TransDesc varchar(1) output
```

Most likely, it should be

```
@TransDesc varchar(256) output
```

instead.

Comment: I have made these corrections and yet it still does not return the description to the top level.

Comment: Try `SELECT @TransDescOut` instead of `SET` ?

Comment: In debug I am noticing that @TransDescOut does not have a value.  Therefore SELECT or SET is not making a difference.

Could the problem be with how the Helper is being executed?

Comment: If you `print @sql1` instead of the exec, does that query return a value?

Comment: Yes: Select Top 1 @TransDesc (a.Description + ' - ' + KF_Vendor.Name) TransDesc 
 from KF_InventoryTransactionType a, KF_OwnerType c, KF_Vendor 
 where a.ID = 1 and KF_Vendor.ID = 108
But now it is saying there is a syntax error near 'a', due to the changes you recommended.

Comment: Prior to your changes, this is what the Dynamic SQL looked like:
(@TransDesc varchar(256) output )Select Top 1 (a.Description + ' - ' + KF_Vendor.Name) TransDesc 
 from KF_InventoryTransactionType a, KF_OwnerType c, KF_Vendor 
 where a.ID = 3 and KF_Vendor.ID = 108
And this is what PRINT @sql1 looked like:
Select Top 1 (a.Description + ' - ' + KF_Vendor.Name) TransDesc 
 from KF_InventoryTransactionType a, KF_OwnerType c, KF_Vendor 
 where a.ID = 3 and KF_Vendor.ID = 108

Comment: +1. @BillMannion You forgot `=` after @TransDesc. You also need to remove `TransDesc`: `set @sql1 = 'Select Top 1 @TransDesc = a.Description + '' - '' + ' + @OwnerStr + '.Name 
from KF_InventoryTransactionType a, KF_OwnerType c, ' + @OwnerStr + ' 
where a.ID = ' + @strTyepID + ' and ' 
+ @OwnerStr + '.ID = ' + @strOwnerID `

Comment: That was it.  So simple yet kept messing me up.  Thanks a lot.